# What kind of number is 2.5000000000000001E-005D ? How can I read or change this?

Tags: java

can someone tell me what exactly means this number? .. i tried too google and read but i cant understand what it does. i am trying to increase that "ViewChance" value but not sure whats the current chance value since i cant understand that number ..can it be changed to increase the "chance"..if so..what is the min and max value ? thanks

```
public static final double ViewChance = 2.5000000000000001E-005D;
```

Comment: From the code you posted it means nothing.

Comment: @Mitch my suspicion is your comment wasn't there when he loaded the page. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number is approximately 2.5 * 10^-5 , or 0.000025, or 25 per million.

ViewChance is not a java reserved word and has no meaning on its own in Java.  The line you gave is defining it as a constant.   To see how "ViewChance" is used, you should first search for "ViewChance" in the class file where it appears.  Since it is defined as "public" the constant may also be used by other source files that import the class -- so search other files for "ViewChance" as well.

You may be able to change it by (1) changing it on the line you found, then (2) running "javac" on the file that you found this line in.  It will *not* change in the running program unless you recompile the class and restart the program.

Comment: i searched all the class files in the jar package and the only ViewChance it appears just in the current class file from where i posted the code line and just once on that line, no other lines having "ViewChance"

Comment: If its not used anywhere, you can delete it to check this is correct. If you can delete it, there is no point changing it.

Comment: Code external to the jar that uses it and imports that class can still potentially use that ViewChance constant.

Comment: Good idea Peter. If he deletes the constant, and rebuilds the jar, then the code that uses the constant should not compile -- and he will get errors pointing to where it is used.

Answer (score 7):

You mean that you don't understand the notation of the number `2.5000000000000001E-005D;`?

It means: 2.5000000000000001 times 10 to the power -5, as type `double`. In "normal" notation, it's the number 0.000025000000000000001.

The `E` stands for "exponent". It means that the number before the `E` is to be multiplied by 10 to the power of the number after the `E`.

The `D` makes it a `double` literal. It's superfluous in this case, because non-integer numeric literals in Java are `double` by default. If would have been an `F` then the number would have been a `float` literal.

Comment: thank you, all the replies are correct wish i could accept  all as right answer

Answer (score 2):

If you had `2.5E-005D` it would be the same as `2.5e-5` which is the same as `2.5/100000` or `0.000025` However, for some reason, a number very slightly larger than this was chosen.

I can only assume the developer computed this value somewhere (with a rounding error) and copy/pasted it.

However, another explanation is that your program has a subtle bug which appears when you use a number like 2.5e-5 but "disappears" for a value slightly different to this. :(